# Streamlit: Series.count() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, streamlit

I am new to streamlit and building an application using data from a csv file. I am trying to apply a function on a dataframe column which gives me an error: `TypeError: Series.count() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given.`

Below is the code:

```
@st.cache_data
def load_data(file):
    data = pd.read_csv(file)
    return data

#Upload a CSV file
uploaded_file = st.file_uploader("Upload a CSV file", type=["csv"])

if uploaded_file is not None:
    data = load_data(uploaded_file)

    if len(data) == 0:
        st.write("No data")

    else:
        column1 = st.selectbox("select a column for filtering (1st box)", data.columns)
        value1 = st.selectbox("select a value for the 1st column", data[column1])

        #create a search box
        search_term = st.text_input("search within the table")

        filtered_data = data[(data[column1] == value1)]

        if search_term:
            filtered_data = filtered_data[filtered_data.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.str.contains(search_term, case=False)).any(axis=1)]

        column_value = filtered_data['PRODUCTNDC']   #storing a value of 'PRODUCTNDC' to a variable

        #calc normalized ndc
        v_rsab = "RXNORM"
        filtered_data['test_ndc'] = normalize_ndc(column_value, v_rsab)
    
        st.dataframe(filtered_data)
```

How can I solve this issue. The function and the script worked perfectly as a python script but integrating it into this application giving me this error.

Comment: Could to tell us the exactly which lines are cause the above error?

Comment: filtered_data['test_ndc'] = normalize_ndc(column_value, v_rsab)

Comment: `normalize_ndc`, could you give us a definition of this func